# Can't map a folder using "net use" command

Tags: windows, mapping, localserver, net-use, public-folders

I wanna map a folder that is shared on a local server. I can do it when I connect to the server like: 
\\192.168.xxx.xxx and just select the folder and map it.

What I can't do is map the folder directly from powershell. 
I'm trying something like this:

net use Z:\\192.168.xxx.xxx\path

What I got after entering the command is "System error 67 has occured, The network name cannot be found"

Does anyone have an idea how this problem can be fixed?
Thanks in advance.
Oskar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try net use Z: \192.168.xxx.xxx\path

Space between z: and the server\path

Comment: Sorry "\" missed - Z: \\192.168.xxx.xxx\path